# exe has triggered a breakpoint in C++ app in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have the following method in a C++ application and every time I call this method in Debug Mode in Visual Studio, I get the debugger saying "MyApp.exe has triggered a breakpoint."

And it breaks on the last curly braces.
I found many messages with this error in SO but none of the solutions worked.

```
void
ShowEvent(HDBOBJ obj)
{
    char *p, buf[16000];
    char priority[256];
    char sDate[256];
    char recno[256];
    char mesgtext[2000];

    /*if (dbAttrGetInt(obj, ATTR_LOG_CURRENT)) {
        sprintf_s(buf, "C\t");
    }
    else {
        sprintf_s(buf, " \t");
    }*/

    dbAttrGetStr(obj, ATTR_LOG_PRIORITY, priority, sizeof(priority) + 1);
    sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "Priority:   %s\n", priority);

    dbAttrGetStr(obj, ATTR_LOG_DATE, sDate, sizeof(sDate) + 1);
    sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "Date:   %s\n", sDate);

    dbAttrGetStr(obj, ATTR_LOG_MAPRECNO, recno, sizeof(recno) + 1);
    sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "RecNo:   %s\n", recno);

    /*if (!strcmp(buf, "(none)")) {
        dbAttrGetStr(obj, ATTR_LOG_MESG, buf, sizeof(buf));
        strncpy(buf, &buf[29], 32);
        if (p = strchr(buf, ' ')) {
            *p = 0;
        }
        buf[32] = 0;
    }*/

    dbAttrGetStr(obj, ATTR_LOG_MESGTEXT, mesgtext, sizeof(mesgtext) + 1);
    sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "MesgText:   %s\n", mesgtext);

    MessageBox(0, buf, "Event Details", MB_OK | MB_OKCANCEL);

} // Breaks here with message "MyApp.exe  has triggered a breakpoint."
```

Comment: `sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "Priority:   %s\n", priority);` - undefined behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't understand your comment. I am new to C++.

Comment: The priority variable is set in the line just above it.

Comment: `buf` is unitialized (the code that did initialize it is commented out), so calling `strlen(buf)` results in Undefined Behavior.